# Does the government of Canada have any say on how its provinces perform their paradiplomacy?

Tags: international-relations, international, canada

> The ministry operates the Quebec Government Offices, de facto
> embassies which serve as communication depots between the Government
> of Quebec and governments outside of Canada. None of the offices in 28
> countries have official diplomatic accreditation, but they serve as
> venues for paradiplomacy.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ministry_of_International_Relations_and_La_Francophonie_(Quebec)

Does the government of Canada has any say on how its provinces perform their paradiplomacy? I've learned that some Canadian provinces perform paradiplomacy to protect and serve their own interest. I was wondering if the Canadian government had any say on how they would go about doing that, or that the paradiplomacy performed by the provinces are completely independent from the foreign policy of the Canadian government.

Comment: 2 things:  first the Federal government probably wants to steer well clear of publicly telling Quebec what to do, due to separatist sensitivities. Second, Quebec has its own immigration rules (predictably predicated on Français uber alles) so having some missions abroad isn't totally unreasonable.